# Algorithm: How to find the number of independent sets in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, independent-set

I'm thinking that there are two cases for each sub-tree: the root is in the independent set and the root is not in the set. How to write a recursive algorithm for finding the number of independent sets in a tree? The tree is n-ary.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)

This is my solution so far, but it isn't correct. The variable parentIncluded is equal to true if the parent of the current subtree is already included in the independent set, thus the root of the current subtree can't be added to the independent set. If parentIncluded is equal to false, then the root of the current subtree can be added to the independent set. There are two cases for when parentIncluded is false. The first case: Add the root to the set. Second case: don't add the root.

```
public static int numberOfIndependentSets(Binary root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return numberOfIndependentSets(root, false) + 1;
    }

    private static int numberOfIndependentSets(Binary current, boolean parentIncluded) {
        if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
            if (parentIncluded) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        int total = 0;
        if (parentIncluded) {
            int left = numberOfIndependentSets(current.left, false);
            int right = numberOfIndependentSets(current.right, false);
           total += (left + 1) * (right + 1) - 1;
        } else {
            // include current node
            int left = numberOfIndependentSets(current.left, true);
            int right = numberOfIndependentSets(current.right, true);
            total = (left+1) *( right +1);

            // not include current node
            left = numberOfIndependentSets(current.left, false);
            right = numberOfIndependentSets(current.right, false);
            total += (left+1) * (right+1) -1;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff  See this Wiki page for the definition of independent set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)

Comment: There's more than 2 cases for each sub-tree. E.g. consider a tree that is a list:  `a->b->c->d`, with `a` as root. There are two independent sets which contain `a`: `{a, c}` and `{a, d}`.

Comment: In pure graph theory, trees don't have roots. They are just acyclc connected graphs. Since specifying a node as the root isn't going to change the answer, i'd be surprised if the root (supposing that one exists) will play a role.

Comment: Are you talking about maximal independent sets? Otherwise make each node a singleton set.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree with you that specifying a node as the root won't alter the answer. The input is a tree, but any node could be the root.

Comment: Do you want to really count the number of independent sets or you just want to find a maximum independent set. Also are you looking for random independent sets or just maximum or maximal? a single vertex is already an independent set

Comment: @Henry. No, I'm not talking about maximal independent sets.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri  I want to count the number of independent sets. The independent set could be maximal or not. Yes, a single vertex is an independent set. An empty set is also an independent set. I need an algorithm for finding the number of independent sets.

Comment: I would focus on a leaf node, chosen at random. Either it is in the independent set or it isn't. If it is in the independent set, then you need to exclude its unique neighbor. If it isn't -- then there is no restriction on which nodes can be chosen from the rest of the graph. This should be enough to get a recursive function to count them.

Comment: @JohnColeman . . . That is a reasonable approach because the leafs are all equivalent (from the perspective of affecting an independent set).  However, you need to consider all subsets of each leaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic idea should work.

You could defined two mutually recursive functions on the set of rooted trees:

```
f(T) = number of independent sets containing the root
g(T) = number of independent sets not containing the root
```

You want to compute `f(T) + g(T)`

For 1-node trees, `L`, as basis cases we have:

```
f(L) = 1
g(L) = 1
```

Say that `T_1, T_2, .. T_n` are the subtrees of the root. Then the recursive equations are:

```
f(T) = g(T_1)*g(T_2)* ... *g(T_n)
g(T) = (f(T_1)+g(T_1))*(f(T_2)+g(T_2)) * ... * (f(T_n)+g(T_n))
```

As a check: you can use this to get the number of independent sets of full binary trees with `n` levels (equivalently, height `n-1`). Make the `f`, `g` a function of level. A Python implementation:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (g(n-1))**2

def g(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (f(n-1) + g(n-1))**2

def h(n): return f(n)+g(n)
```

`[h(n) for n in range(1,7)]` evaluates to

```
2, 5, 41, 2306, 8143397, 94592167328105
```

This is sequence [A076725](http://oeis.org/A076725) in the Online Encyclopedia (slightly shifted) which is described as "the number of independent sets on a complete binary tree with 2^(n-1)-1 nodes", so it seems that this approach makes sense.

Comment: Very nice explanation of the recurrence ! Beautiful !